# How to extract H264 frames using live555

Tags: c++, video-streaming, h.264, codec, live555

There's simply no full example anywhere. In live555 folders, there's the following program: [testRTSPClient.cpp](https://github.com/rgaufman/live555/blob/master/testProgs/testRTSPClient.cpp) which accesses an RTSP and receives raw RTP packets but do nothing with them. It receives them through the `DummySink` class.

There is an [example](https://github.com/yuvalk/demoLive555withFFMPEG) on how to use `testRTSPClient.cpp` to receive NAL units from h264, but live555 has custom sink classes specifically for each codec, so it's a lot better to use them. Example: [H264or5VideoRTPSink.cpp](https://github.com/rgaufman/live555/blob/master/liveMedia/H264or5VideoRTPSink.cpp).

So if I substitute an instance of `DummySink` with an instance of a subclass of `H264or5VideoRTPSink` in `testRTSPClient.cpp` and make this subclass receive the frames I think it might work.

If I just follow the implementation of `DummySink` I just need to write something like this:

```
class MyH264VideoRTPSink: public H264VideoRTPSink {
    public:
        static MyH264VideoRTPSink* createNew(UsageEnvironment& env,
                        MediaSubsession& subsession, // identifies the kind of data that's being received
                        char const* streamId = NULL); // identifies the stream itself (optional)

    private:
        MyH264VideoRTPSink(UsageEnvironment& env, MediaSubsession& subsession, char const* streamId);
            // called only by "createNew()"
        virtual ~MyH264VideoRTPSink();

        static void afterGettingFrame(void* clientData, unsigned frameSize,
                                      unsigned numTruncatedBytes,
                                      struct timeval presentationTime,
                                      unsigned durationInMicroseconds);
        void afterGettingFrame(unsigned frameSize, unsigned numTruncatedBytes,
                    struct timeval presentationTime, unsigned durationInMicroseconds);

        // redefined virtual functions:
        virtual Boolean continuePlaying();

        u_int8_t* fReceiveBuffer;
        MediaSubsession& fSubsession;
        char* fStreamId;
};
```

If we look at `DummySink` it suggests that `afterGettingFrame` is the function that receives frames. But where is the frame received? How can I access it?

```
void DummySink::afterGettingFrame(unsigned frameSize, unsigned numTruncatedBytes,
                  struct timeval presentationTime, unsigned /*durationInMicroseconds*/) {
// We've just received a frame of data.  (Optionally) print out information about it:
```

**UPDATE:**

I created my own H264 Sink class: https://github.com/lucaszanella/jscam/blob/f6b38eea2934519bcccd76c8d3aee7f58793da00/src/jscam/android/app/src/main/cpp/MyH264VideoRTPSink.cpp but it has a `createNew` different from the one in `DummySink`:

```
createNew(UsageEnvironment& env, Groupsock* RTPgs, unsigned char rtpPayloadFormat);
```

There's simply no mention of what `RTPgs` is meant to be, neither `rtpPayloadFormat`. I don't even know if I'm on the right track...

Comment: Are you succeeded in extracting h264 data using H264VideoRTPSink

Comment: @Riskhan I didn't even try, that thing is very bad coded and bad documented. I used https://github.com/Ansersion/myRtspClient

Comment: Yes you are right.  I will try with above link.  Thanks bro for immediate reply

Comment: @Riskhan the examples it has in the examples folder are very useful, and you can also see what I did: https://github.com/lucaszanella/orwell/blob/548adbb637fba32b3dd26734fbca7ea50ec44907/cpp/common/MediaStream.cpp it's very poorly coded because I didn't clean things yet but take a look

Comment: Ok yaar. I will look at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first confusion is betweeen Source & Sink, the [FAQ](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/faq.html) decribe briefly the workflow:

> 'source1' -> 'source2' (a filter) -> 'source3' (a filter) -> 'sink'

The class `H264VideoRTPSink` is made to publish data through RTP, not to consume data.

In the case of the RTSP client sample [testRTSPClient.cpp](https://github.com/rgaufman/live555/blob/master/testProgs/testRTSPClient.cpp), the source which depends on the codec is created processing the DESCRIBE answer calling `MediaSession::createNew`.

The Sink doesnot depend on the codec, the `startPlaying` method on the `MediaSink` register the callback `afterGettingFrame` to be called when data will be received by the source. Next when this callback is executed you should call `continuePlaying` to register it again for next incoming data.

In `DummySink::afterGettingFrame` the buffer contains the H264 elementary stream frames extract from RTP buffer.

In order to dump H264 elementary stream frame you can have a look to [h264bitstream](https://github.com/aizvorski/h264bitstream)

Comment: That's odd. In the `testRTSPClient.cpp` it explicitly says that DummySink is needed to receive frames. So `H264VideoRTPSink` should receive and parse h264 frames. If `H264VideoRTPSink` is to send, shouldn't `H264VideoRTPSource` be to receive? I mean, why didn't `live555` implement some of this if it's the main thing the library needs to do? I'm ok with doing the h264bitstrem but I thought that all those sinks (h265, audio sinks, etc) were for that. It'll be hard to implement every one of them

Comment: Yes the DummySink is the consumer that receive frames received from the FramedSource that is created from the SDP information, you can see this in [MediaSession](https://github.com/rgaufman/live555/blob/master/liveMedia/MediaSession.cpp) that create the H264VideoRTPSource. Next the DummySink do what it like with these frames, writing, streaming, decoding....